# Clean/Rebuild Solution Before Publishing To Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, msbuild

I have a solution which include loosely coupled projects with a ASP.Net MVC application. I have set the output of all projects to 'MvcProject\bin' folder. So, I need to Clean/Rebuild the solution before I will be able to run my web application. The problem is that when I publish this to Azure or Local system then it will not include all the project dlls(and its dependent dlls, it will only include MvcProject and its dependent dlls). Is there is any way to tell the VS(or msbuild) to clean/rebuild the solution and include all the related project dlls which output is set to 'MvcProject\bin'

Comment: Cloud projects in MSBuild pull in all dependencies of your MvcProject recursively. Can you add your other "loosely coupled" projects into referenced projects of MvcProject? That will solve your problem.

Comment: @SevaTitov, no I cannot. This is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did. First of all edited all my class-library projects csproj file OutPath to,

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' "> 
    ..................................
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    ..................................


<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' "> 
    ..................................
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    ..................................
```

Next add this to my MVC application csproj file bottom(before `</Project>`),

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="..\Project1\bin\$(Configuration)\**\*;..\Project2\bin\$(Configuration)\**\*" />
        ................................................................
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_CustomFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(_CustomFiles->'bin\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```

Finally add this to my Azure.pubxml(you can find it in `Properties/PublishProfiles`) file bottom(before `</Project>`),

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
         <_CustomFiles Include="..\Project1\bin\$(Configuration)\**\*;..\Project2\bin\$(Configuration)\**\*" />
            ................................................................
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```